# How can i access an asp.net website remotely with real IP address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost, remote-access, web-hosting

I have a web-service / website (with database) which is developed by asp.net MVC in Visual Studio. Currently, it is running on localhost.

But I would like to access this website through internet from another location. In this case, what are the steps to be taken?? Can anybody enlighten me in this regard?

[Note: I am new to this concept, I have googled this issues already ; However, no luck so far]

Answer (score 0):

First

You should have a valid IP for your internet ,Your ISP can take care of that.

Then you should create a new website in your IIS application,

Then publish your website in visual studio in a folder and copy content of that folder to a folder which your newly created IIS website points to.

Then you should tell IIS which port you want to use and open that port in your firewall.

You can Google for creating new website in IIS,It has easy steps.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with web.config file in asp.net mvc project ? Do  i have to tweak anything here and there?

Comment: It depends on your project,When you publish it on IIS you will get errors if you did anything wrong and you can correct them or edit web.config file.